# Only Macintosh shown on Startup Manager after Windows 10 32-bit Boot Camp install

Tags: bootcamp, 32-bit

I installed Boot Camp with Windows 10 32-bit, but it doesnt give me the option to switch my Mac into Windows. Any help? I've tried holding option when restarting it but only the Macintosh box appears.

Answer (score 1):

32-bit versions of Windows 10 are not supported on any Mac model. You need to install the 64-bit version.

From [Apple KB: How to install Windows using Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/HT201468)

> Before you begin, make sure you have everything you need:
>
> - An Intel-based Mac
> - A Microsoft Windows installation media or disk image (ISO) containing a 64-bit version of Microsoft Windows 8 or later

See [this list](https://support.apple.com/HT204990#models) for which Mac models support Windows 10.